# SwiftUI macOS Sandboxed application active read the .ssh/config file

Tags: swift, macos, file, swiftui, appstore-sandbox

I have Sandboxed application active I need to read the following `.ssh/config` file.

But I am having the following error:

```
Ooops! Something went wrong: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 
"The file “config” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." 
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/name/Library/Containers/sa.GitRepository/Data//.ssh/config, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x600003ccf120 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Can you tell me how I can solve the problem?

Code:

```swift
guard let desktopPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory,
                                                                    .userDomainMask,
                                                                    true).first else { return }
        _path = State(initialValue: desktopPath)
        let pathConfig = desktopPath.replacingOccurrences(of: "Desktop", with: "/.ssh/config")
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: pathConfig, encoding: .utf8)
            let myStrings = contents.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            let users =  myStrings.filter { $0.contains("github.com-") }.map {$0.replacingOccurrences(of: "Host github.com-", with: "")}
            if(users.count > 0){ _user = State(initialValue: users[0]) }
            _userArray = State(initialValue: users)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: User's home should not be available in Sandbox.

Comment: So there is no solution to the problem other than to disable Sandboxed application?

Comment: "I have Sandboxed application active I need to read the following .ssh/config file."  Does that mean you are allowed to access any file without user's content?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to be able to read that file, isn't there a way to ask for permissions or something similar for mac os?

Comment: The only way is that the user must give permission via `NSOpenPanel`. Right afterwards you can create a security scoped bookmark for permanent permission

Comment: @vadian: I didn't quite understand how I can do this part: Right afterwards you can create a security scoped bookmark for permanent permission

Can you tell me where I can find some guides?

Comment: Google search **Security scoped bookmarks** [first result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep_element/bookmark/enabling_security-scoped_bookmark_and_url_access). There are two links with an example.